# Having problems with Spring webflow

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-webflow

I am trying to add a `on-render` element to this XML:

```
<var name="someVariable" class="com.example.test"/>

<view-state id="frontpage" view="test/test">    
    <binder>
        <binding property="test" required="true"/>
    </binder>     
    <transition on="submit" to="summary">
        <evaluate expression="myExpression.test()"/>
    </transition>
</view-state>
```

I tried adding it in the `view-state` element, but when I do so, the page crash. This is the exception:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content
>   was found starting with element 'binder'. One of
>   '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":transition,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":on-exit,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":exception-handler}' is
>   expected.

I am using Spring webflow 2.0.8.

Comment: I don't see any `on-render` in your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WebFlow XSD](http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd) specifies that any `<binder>` element must come before any `<on-render>` element. The exception message you got is because your `on-render` element was appearing before the `<binder>` element. I suggest that you use an XSD-aware editor for editing XML files, and include the webflow XSD in the XML declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd"
      start-state="startState">

...

</flow>
```